# trimming column named is generating ValueError

Tags: pandas

I have a table which I run through a function to trim its columns down to length 128 (I know it's really long, there isn't anything I can do about that) characters so it can use to_sql to create a database from it.

```
def truncate_column_names(df, length):
    rename = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        if len(col) > length:
            new_col = col[:length-3]+"..."
            rename[col] = new_col
    result = df.rename(columns=rename)
    return result
```

This function works fine and I get a table out just fine but the problem comes when I tried to save the file I get the error

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

The method I have doing some housekeeping before saving to a file included dropping duplicates and that is where this error is being spit out. I tested this by saving the original dataFrame and then just loading it, running the truncate function, and then trying drop_duplicates on the result and I get the same error.

The headers for the file before I try truncating looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/WXmvwHDg

I trimmed the file down to 1 record and still have the problem.

Comment: IIUC you can just do `df.columns = df.columns.str[:128]`

Comment: Thanks that will certainly be faster but I still have the ValueError using that method.

Comment: I can't comment on the writing to file part, does it work fine when you write to csv? is the problem only when writing to SQL?

Comment: drop_duplicates is what was throwing the error. I just have a method to do some checks before saving to csv that include dropping any duplicate records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a result of the truncating causing some columns to have non-unique names.

To confirm this was an issue I did a short test:

```
In [113]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ab", "ac", "ad"])

In [114]: df
Out[114]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ab, ac, ad]
Index: []

In [115]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[115]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ab, ac, ad]
Index: []

In [116]: df.columns
Out[116]: Index([u'ab', u'ac', u'ad'], dtype='object')

In [117]: df.columns = df.columns.str[:1]

In [118]: df
Out[118]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, a, a]
Index: []

In [119]: df.drop_duplicates()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-daf275b6788b> in <module>()
----> 1 df.drop_duplicates()

C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kw
args)
     86                 else:
     87                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
---> 88             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     89         return wrapper
     90     return _deprecate_kwarg

C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in drop_duplicates(self, su
bset, take_last, inplace)
   2826         deduplicated : DataFrame
   2827         """
-> 2828         duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, take_last=take_last)
   2829
   2830         if inplace:

C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kw
args)
     86                 else:
     87                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
---> 88             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     89         return wrapper
     90     return _deprecate_kwarg

C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in duplicated(self, subset,
 take_last)
   2871
   2872         vals = (self[col].values for col in subset)
-> 2873         labels, shape = map(list, zip( * map(f, vals)))
   2874
   2875         ids = get_group_index(labels, shape, sort=False, xnull=False)

C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in f(vals)
   2860
   2861         def f(vals):
-> 2862             labels, shape = factorize(vals, size_hint=min(len(self), _SI
ZE_HINT_LIMIT))
   2863             return labels.astype('i8',copy=False), len(shape)
   2864

C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.pyc in factorize(values, s
ort, order, na_sentinel, size_hint)
    133     table = hash_klass(size_hint or len(vals))
    134     uniques = vec_klass()
--> 135     labels = table.get_labels(vals, uniques, 0, na_sentinel)
    136
    137     labels = com._ensure_platform_int(labels)

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels (pandas\ha
shtable.c:13946)()

ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

and got the same result. using df.columns.unique() after the truncation i had ~200 duplicate columns after the truncation

Comment: If this is the issue then you need some kind of column mangling func that checks the column doesn't already exist

Comment: yes precisely or manage the duplicate column names in some fashion at least.